# How do I prove that a function is onto and/or one-to-one?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Say I have $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ and I'm given these functions:

- $f(x) = x+5$
- $f(x) = 3x-2$
- $f(x) = 5-x$

How do I know if it is onto or one-to-one without using graphs?

Comment: What do you mean "which function is what"? The functional expressions are right there. What more are you after?

Comment: What definitions are you using for one-to-one? onto?  What have you attempted?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Definition of one-to-one function

We have $$\forall a,b \in \Bbb {Z}, f(a)=f(b)\implies a=b $$

So, for example, for $f(x)=x+5$

Suppose $f(x)=f(y),$$\;$We$\,$ have $$x+5=y+5$$
Thus, $$x=y$$

Therefore, $f(x)=x+5$ is one-to-one function

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, and also for onto. If none of the examples I gave are onto, can you give me an example please?

Comment: Determined $f(x):A\rightarrow B$, So f is onto function $\iff$ $\forall y \in B,\exists x \in A, f(x)=y$

and from this definition, $f(x)=3x-2$ isn't onto function. why?....

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead and use brute force: the definition. Let $x_1, x_2\in \mathbb{Z}$ Then if $x_1\neq x_2$ then $x_1+5\neq x_2+5$ and hence the first function is injective. Exact same reasoning for the other two functions. Concerning surjectivity or ontoness. Can any integer $y$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ be written as $5-x$ for some specific $x$? Yes, because this simply amounts to solving the equation $y=5-x$ with $x$ as the unknown! thus the third function is onto. Same exact reasoning again for the other two functions!